# Html form not submitting data

Tags: html, forms, input

This html form is not submitting data and i don't know why.I have tried to find the error and i do not seem to get around it,any help will be gladly appreciated

```
{% extends 'registration/base.html' %}

 {% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block title %}Create account{% endblock %}


{% block body %} 
 <div class="container" style="padding-top:20px">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 card jumbotron ">
        <h2><span class="badge badge-light">Create Account</span></h2><br>
        <form action="{% url 'tzuzz:create_account' %}"  method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
           <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email </label>
                <input class="form-control is-valid" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                <label>Names</label>
                <input class="form-control is-valid" type="text" name="names" placeholder="Enter first and last name">
                <label>Sex</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="sex">
                    <option>Male</option>
                    <option>Female</option>
                </select>
                <label>Date of birth</label>
                <input class="form-control is-valid" name="date" type="date">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input class="form-control is-valid" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
           <button class="btn btn-secondary">Login</button>
        </form>
        <br><br>
           {% if error %}
               <p class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show"  role="alert">
                  {{error}}
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                 </button>
               </p>
           {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

{% endblock %}

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with this (not that would stop the form from submitting anyway). What makes you think it is failing to submit? Have you checked the Network tab of the developer tools in your browser? Is *any* request made? Does it have any data in the body?

Answer (score -2):

Here is the answer i forgot to include type submit in my button           
     `<button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Login</button>`

Comment: `submit` is the **default** value for `type` on a `<button>` element.